# dplyr - Separate rows from data frame using cumulative sum of values from a column and average of values from other column

Tags: r, dplyr

I do not have an exact idea of separating rows from a data frame based on cumulative sum of a column from selected rows and average of values from another column.

Sample data frame:

```
          ID Weight Units
16-1791-9731    299    50
16-1791-9732    301    72
16-1791-9730    301    34
16-1787-9720    296    78
16-1787-9719    297    98
16-1787-9717    300    98
16-1787-9718    301    98
16-1782-9700    297    74
16-1782-9699    299    74
16-1782-9703    301   104
16-1782-9702    303   140
16-1785-9710    298    77
16-1785-9708    298    77
16-1785-9711    299   200
16-1785-9709    300   200
16-1265-7695    299    72
```

[Image of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhyX8.png)

For example, how to pull 2 sets of 4 rows each as separate data frames with **Units** average as 61 and cumulative sum of **weight** within a range of 800 to 1100.
The rows selected to the new data frames should also be removed from master df.

Actual working dataframe - [enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YPpTHkho1VIM3ZeHdvlwWl0C68fwsLjuZw8AaXMsjVM/edit?usp=sharing)
I am trying to pull rows from dataframes with the best possible method that is closer to the criteria specified earlier. (cumulative sum of weight ranging between 800 and 1100 and average of selected PotOG at 400 (between 400 and 420)

Steps to work on
 1) To identify 3-4 rows (Approx. where weight range of selection falls between 800 and 1100)
 2) Identify the average of PotOG (from weighted average)
 3) Identify PotOG range between 400 and 420.
 4) The best fitting rows are pulled out as a cluster to new dataframe (also removed from master.
 5) Repeat process for further requests

Any suggestions to achieve this in dplyr?

Comment: Can you post the input and expected output in a format that we can feed into R. That makes helping you easier.

Comment: it sounds more like an algorithm question to me. I think there is no quick and easy way to do it in dplyr

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for because you have not shown expected output and your criteria and input data provide zero cases that meet conditions outlined. However, here is one approach to the problem I can come up with.

```
# Get all possible combinations of four rows
combn_df <- as.data.frame(t(combn(1:nrow(df), 4, sort)))

# Test each combination of four rows for both conditions
combn_df$weightsInRange <- apply(combn_df, 1, function(x) between(sum(df$Weight[x]), 800, 1100))
combn_df$unitsMean61 <- apply(combn_df, 1, function(x) mean(df$Units[x[1:4]]) == 61)

# Select combinations of rows that meet both conditions
combn_df <- combn_df[combn_df$weightsInRange & combn_df$unitsMean61, ]

# Extract two sets of four rows from original DF into two separate data frames
apply(combn_df[1:2, ], 1, function(x) df[x[1:4], ])
```

Comment: I have now edited my question to include the original data frame that I am working on. I will give this a try.